# Model View Presenter for Qt C++ development

Tags: c++, qt4

Can somebody point me to a good tutorial or sample project where MVP pattern has been implemented using Qt C++. I'm new to Qt as I come from VB.NET background. MVP is pretty common in VB.NET. Doing a Google search was not so fruitful either. Please somebody show me some real world example. Like in VB.NET we create complex model with IList of some base model. All these things are important. And what relevant data structures should be used where we used the Collection class for example.

Comment: MVC (Model-View-Controller) is probably what you should be searching for (Google search for "MVC Qt" gives a [relevant hit in the Qt reference documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/model-view-programming.html))

Comment: I think MVP has evolved from MVC and has lot more advantages than MVC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To learn MVP, I suggest reading Michael Feather's article "The Humble Dialog Box":

[webarchive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150920084545/http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/TheHumbleDialogBox.pdf)

(This is one specific form of MVP, there are other variants possible.)

The examples in that article are made with C++. There are not made with Qt, but more or less independent of the GUI framework. MVP is about the separation of your code into a framework dependent part and a framework-independent part, which can be learned by using almost any GUI framework.

Comment: If you take a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/DotNetMVPFramework_Part1.aspx) about MVP in .NET and tell me that the same thing can be achieved in QT C++ then I'll be glad.

Comment: The article is not only about the MVP pattern, it is about creating a MVP framework. MVP itself is described in the first part without any language specific details, so yes, MVP can be done in C++ with almost any GUI framework. To create a complete MVP framework, however, there's more required. The solution in the article seems to make heavy use of reflection attributes, something you don't have at hand in C++. Is it that what you want? In C++, one would solve these issues probably in a different manner.

Comment: How would I handle Reflection in C++ then?

Comment: @Soham: what exactly do you want? A four line answer how to create an MVP framework like the one described in that article using C++ and Qt? Good luck.

Comment: @Soham: having a 2nd look into the article, I must say I was wrong, reflection is not used very much. So in theory it should be (more or less) easily possible to port that framwork to C++. But as I asked you before - are you *really* sure that this is what you want?

Comment: @Doc Brown: This is exactly what I want because I've been working on this platform for a long time. So how would you suggest I start?

Comment: @Doc Brown: One thing I didn't get any idea of is using an Interface (as in Interface and Abstract class, not User Interface) through which we will pass the data to the Presenter class. How am I supposed to do this using QT and C++.

Comment: @Soham: what exactly is your problem? You create an interface for this purpose just the way you create any interface in C++ - as a class with only pure virtual functions. Use multiple inheritance to inherit your dialogs from both the Qt dialog classes and your interface class. Read Michael Feather's article, it is all in there.

Comment: I've blogged a PyQt implementation Michael Feather's paper. It's easily convertible to C++ Qt: http://duganchen.ca/a-humble-dialog-implementation-in-pyqt/